# WP API post__not_in is not working

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

I'm using WP API to get posts in my application and I'm trying to exclude some posts from query using `filter[post__not_in]`.
after removing `filter` in WP **4.7**, I'm using `WP REST API filter parameter` plugin to get it back. and it works for all parameters but for `post__not_in` it's not effecting at all, I still get all posts.

I saw some closed issues about this on WP API repo on github, they said that `post__not_in` are not allowed for unauthenticated requests, I also found merged PR claimed that they fixed it, but I tried to use this function

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'post__in';
    $vars[] = 'post__not_in';
    return $vars;
});
```

but now whatever I pass to `post__not_in` I get empty response

any ideas how to exclude post in WP API?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit more complicated to achieve. It needs too filters :

- one to allow the new REST parameter
- another to set the WP_Query argument

```php
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'collection_params', null, 2 );
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'query', null, 2 );

function collection_params( array $query_params, \WP_Post_Type $post_type ): array {
    $query_params['post__not_in'] = [
        'description' => 'Excludes posts.',
        'type'        => 'array',
        'default'     => [],
    ];

    return $query_params;
}

function query( $args, \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    if ( isset( $request['post__not_in'] ) && count( $request['post__not_in'] ) ) {
        $args ['post__not_in'] = $request['post__not_in'];
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at least in 2023 there is no need for `post__in` or `post__not_in` request parameters since there are custom parameters now inside wp-json request parameters: `include` & `exclude`, both take a comma-separated list of items and should cover your needs.